# Animation after submitting a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, animation

I have a div container with a form field in my HTML:

```
<div class="flex_item" id="b_one">
    <form id="f_one">
         <input id="i_one" type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now i'm trying to change the backgroundcolor of the div by writing the requested color in the input field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f_one").submit(function () {
        var input = $("i_one").val();
        $("#b_one").animate({left: '75px', width: '-150px'}, callbackColor('#b_one', '#i_one', input));
    });
});
function callbackColor(container, i_number, color) {
    return function () {
        $(container).css('background-color', color);
        $(i_number).css('background-color', color);
        $(container).animate({left: '75px', width: '300px'});
    }
}
```

My problem is that the animation doesn't work when i'm using a submit event handler.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Just by pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default behavior of a form when submitting. An event is available to you after a event handler is fired. `animate` function also takes a speed parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#f_one").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input = $("#i_one").val();
        $("#b_one").animate({left: '75px', width: '-150px'}, 1000, callbackColor('#b_one', '#i_one', input));
    });
});

function callbackColor(container, i_number, color) {
    $(container).css('background-color', color);
    $(i_number).css('background-color', color);
    $(container).animate({left: '75px', width: '300px'});
}
```

Another thought, you also don't need to return the function from your callback, though it's not related to your problem.